# Facebook fan page only partially loads

Tags: facebook

I created a fan page based on html css. 
I also added some plugins: like, comments and share.

Sometimes (especially first time the fan page is loaded) only a part of the page is loaded and also the like button is not displayed.
when I refresh the page most of the times it is displayed correctly.

Can you please tell me why?
Any help will be appreciated!

Here is a [link](http://www.facebook.com/pages/%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A5-%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7-%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%94/320166694662708?sk=app_153284594738391&app_data=dlt) to the page:

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `body` ([iframe](http://153284594738391.iframehost.com/526640))

You might wanted to add

```
body
{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Which only hides horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Hi webarto, thanks for your response.
I do not have body tag in my fan page - the whole page is in html table.
I also do not have overflow:hidden on my fan page.

As I said sometimes the whole page is loaded and works great and sometimes only a part of it is loaded and also the like plugin I added is not loaded.

Can someone tell me what can I do about it?

Comment: Hi, please take a look here http://pokit.org/get/648b681692aefafb3c28b3fd0f19ec63.png, I highlighted that part, please remove it and try.

Comment: Thanks again! I added:
body{ overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;}

But still - if I clear the history of the browser and load the page the like button I added is not showing if I refresh (F5) it is shown.
Any ideas?